# How can I change syntax of a single file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a file called `env.config` in Visual Studio 2015, that I would like to be structured as JSON. How can I get syntax highlighting on that file (no other config) file to be JSON? I don't want to change all `.config` files extensions to have JSON syntax highlighting.

In sublime I would have:

1. Dragged my mouse to bottom right corner of screen
2. Click the language, and select a new one

Comment: Right-click the file and choose Open With.  Pick "JSON Editor".  This is supposed to be discoverable btw, you might want to take a couple of hours to click around some more, it can save you a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks. I would not have expected 'Open With' to work any differently in Visual Studio to how it works in the OS. Especially since coming from Sublime, you can select 'Open With' and it will launch your file within that program externally to Sublime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above:

1. Right click the file in the solution explorer
2. Choose the 'Open with' option